# JQuery 101 - Changing text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, toggle

I have a link to hide/display some text:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_status_history">show/hide history<a/>
```

The corresponding JavaScript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle_status_history').click(function() {
    if ($('#status_history').is(":hidden")) {
      $('#status_history').slideDown("fast");
    } else {
      $('#status_history').slideUp("fast");
    }
  });
```

It works great, but I'd like to toggle the hyperlink text as well. What do I need to do to modify the 'show/hide history' to show either 'hide history' (if it's currently displayed) or 'show history' if it's currently hidden? Something like this..?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle_status_history').click(function() {
    if ($('#status_history').is(":hidden")) {
      $('#status_history').slideDown("fast");
      // SOMETHING HERE TO SET TEXT TO 'HIDE HISTORY'
    } else {
      $('#status_history').slideUp("fast");
      // SOMETHING HERE TO SET TEXT TO 'SHOW HISTORY'
    }
  });
```

**Disclaimer:** I have less than an hour of experience with JQuery (and I haven't used JavaScript since the late-90s) - I'm just trying to modify a code sample for my site. I've looked at the API for the toggle() and replaceWith() functions but am not getting it to work. Googling and RTFM'ing hasn't helped me so far.

Comment: SO, click the checkbox next to the answer that fixed your issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('#status_history').text("Whatever you want it to say");
```

Have a look at the [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page). They have a very good documentation which explains everything, with examples. For example, the [`.text(str);`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function is underneath [`manipulation`](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#toggle_status_history').text("Show history");
```

Comment: Wow - thanks for all the quick replies! I tried using .val and .html earlier with no luck. 


   $("#toggle_status_history").text('New text'); // WORKS

Thankyou everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

`$('#status_history').text("Hide/Show History");` is what you need.
The better way of doing such things is using toggle method provided by jQuery, it accepts a list of functions which will be looped on each click. So that you don't need to do `is(':hidden')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#status_history').val("bla bla bla..");
```

try this...
fn.val() is getting the value of input, select or textarea's value or text ;)
fn.val(newValue) is setting new values ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle_status_history').click(function() {
   $('#status_history').toggle('slow')
   $("#toggle_status_history").text(($("#toggle_status_history").text()=='show')?'hide':'show');
}
});
```